# @SpyBean-ed class's private fields in multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have an integration `@SpringBootTest` which implies an other background thread too.

From test's thread (!) some public method calls modify a private field of `@SpyBean`-ed instance (`@Scope` in singleton).

The problem is that calls from the background thread see nothing from this change!

After hours of debugging (e.g. trying volatile) I explored the `@SpyBean`-ed instance and found that mentioned field (`_state`) really differs between referenced and wrapped instances (assuming `spiedInstance` means the wrapped one) along other private fields too.

[image: exploring spybean instance]

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I simplified my environment to help reproducing.

```
@Service
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class TestServiceImpl {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestServiceImpl.class);

    private final TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    private volatile int value = 0;
    private volatile boolean isEnabled = false;

    @Autowired
    public TestServiceImpl(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;

        taskExecutor.execute(() -> pingToLog());
    }

    private void pingToLog() {
        while(true) {
            logger.debug(String.valueOf(value));

            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // no op
            }
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BicisoApplication.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class TestServiceTest {

    @SpyBean
    protected TestServiceImpl testService;

    @Test
    public void doTest() {

        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // no op
        }

        testService.setValue(1);

        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // no op
        }
    }
}
```

Expected: after some "TestServiceImpl - 0" lines in the log
some "TestServiceImpl - 1" lines should appear.

Current investigation results: if I move out execute's call from the constructor and put into public method and call through proxy it will
work as expected.

But `TestServiceImpl` above is a simplification. In real code the class subscribes in constructor to an event which will be triggered by other 
threads. This subsciption has a reference to original instance, not the spy wrapper so the problem raises.

UPDATE2:
It seems `@SpyBean` creates a new instance instead using the one already
in context. I still think it is a bug: `@SpyBean` should wrap the existing instance not duplicate instance and duplicate its possibly-already-in-use fields.

UPDATE3:
Suddently the result is the situation is documented already.
Mockito's documentation contains the following under *Spying on real objects* section:

> *Mockito **does not** delegate calls to the passed real instance, instead it actually creates a copy of it. So if you keep the real instance and interact with it, don't expect the spied to be aware of those interaction and their effect on real instance state. The corollary is that when an **unstubbed** method is called **on the spy** but **not on the real instance**, you won't see any effects on the real instance.*

I feel this a really missleading implementation!
It is not a **spy** but a **hiderAndReplacer** feature. :(

Sorry about wasting Your time.

Comment: Consider posting an answer by yourself so this question wouldn't appear as "unanswered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suddently the result is the situation is documented already, at least You reverse-engineered the problem till You learn **not to trust evident meaning of words**, but look for docs. Mockito's documentation contains the following under *Spying on real objects* section:

> Mockito **does not** delegate calls to the passed real instance, instead it actually creates a copy of it. So if you keep the real instance and interact with it, don't expect the spied to be aware of those interaction and their effect on real instance state. The corollary is that when an **unstubbed** method is called **on the spy** but **not on the real instance**, you won't see any effects on the real instance.

I feel this a really missleading implementation! It is not a **spy** but a **hiderAndReplacer** feature. :(

Sorry about wasting Your time.